# Cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager

Tags: android

here i'm getting the error: "Cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager" though i have added the import statement for it. I can't seem to understand the problem. Can anyone help?

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.veeresh.parsegeo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class AgentsDropdownOnItemClickListener  implements OnItemClickListener {
public String selectedItemTag;

public GoogleMap mMap;
MapsActivity agent = new MapsActivity();

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {


    Context mContext = v.getContext();
    MapsActivity mainActivity = ((MapsActivity) mContext);


    Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
    fadeInAnimation.setDuration(10);
    v.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);


    mainActivity.popupWindowDogs.dismiss();



    selectedItemTag = ((TextView) v).getTag().toString();
    if ( selectedItemTag.equals("VISA")) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Agent ID is: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mMap == null) {
                        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
                        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                .getMap();
                        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
                        if (mMap != null) {
                           agent.setUpMapVisa();
                        }
                    }
        mMap.clear();
        agent.setUpMapAadhar();
    }



}

}
```

Comment: Try extending FragmentActivity for the class

Comment: Yay, that solved the cannot resolve problem. Now i get a null pointer exception for line:    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                    .getMap();

Comment: Biggest question... Why do you have a listener declared in its own class?

Comment: i did not get you @inner_class7

Comment: You do not need to create a separate class to declare an onItemClickListener you can create this in your Activity rather than on it's own

Answer (score 0):

**You should extend `FragmentActivity` for the class**. Do it as below

```
public class AgentsDropdownOnItemClickListener extends FragmentActivity  implements OnItemClickListener{
```

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) for more info.

Comment: you are not loading any views..where is the fragment declared? i mean the xml file..

Comment: Now i get a null pointer exception for line: mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)) .getMap(); –

Comment: it is set as the layout for another java class

Answer (score 0):

You obviously not showing the entire activity.

In any case what you should do is make sure the activity which actually contains the map is the one you are requesting to find the view from.

That means:
**If the map view is in the "MapsACtivity"** you should write something like this:

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                            .getMap();
```

And of course make sure the mainActivity extends FragmentActivity.

More info on findViewByID can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int)).

Answer (score 0):

Try to instead of `public class MainActivity extends Activity`

`public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity`

Also check and make sure importing SupportLibrary like:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Now, you can use `getSupportFragmentManager()`